# Extending Array<number>

Tags: typescript

Why does the following not work as expected:

```
class MyArray extends Array<number>
{
    constructor(n: number)
    {
        super(n);
    }
}

function initalize()
{
    var myArray = new MyArray(4);
    var l = myArray.length; // l should be 4
}
```

"l" turns out to be 0 instead of 4, which I expected. It doesn't make a difference whether I implement a constructor in "MyArray" or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code transpiles to

```
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || function (d, b) {
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
};
var MyArray = (function (_super) {
    __extends(MyArray, _super);
    function MyArray(n) {
        _super.call(this, n);
    }
    return MyArray;
})(Array);
function initalize() {
    var myArray = new MyArray(4);
    var l = myArray.length; // l should be 4
}
```

And the problem is that you no longer deal with the original native type that has special properties. So your extended type - even if you would have succeeded - would be severely limited and confusing for others.

Details and gotchas can be found Axel Rauschmayer's article: http://www.2ality.com/2013/03/subclassing-builtins-es6.html

Comment: I accept this as an answer, and it looks like there is no workaround. I would prefer Typescript would not allow such constructs, because they don't make sense.

Comment: @Gerhard Yes, Typescript is far from being a truly mature language, even though the syntax itself pretty much feels complete. Anyways, there _is_ a workaround: an internal `Array` instance, and all of its methods replicated on your type, all of which only invoke the corresponding methods on the internal `Array` object.

Comment: @John that is what I tried, but did not succeed to implement an indexer to access array elements with myArray[i].

Comment: @Gerhard AFAIK, numeric indexers for Arrays are just numeric-like properties. You should be able to set the corresponding numeric-like property on your wrapper object when an element is added to the internal array.